# Error while adding new documents to Azure Search index

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index with a couple of fields of type `Edm.String` and `Collection(Edm.String)`. I want to have another index with the same fields plus another field of type `Edm.Double`. When I create such an index and try to add the same values (plus the newly added `Edm.Double` value) as I did to the first index, I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid. Details: parameters : An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.\r\n"
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what this error means? I tried looking for it on the Internet but I couldn't find anything related to my situation. A sample request I'm sending to the new index looks like this:

```
POST https://myservicename.search.windows.net/indexes/newindexname/docs/index?api-version=2016-09-01

{
    "value": [{
        "@search.action": "upload",
        "keywords": ["red", "lovely", "glowing", "cute"],
        "name": "sample document",
        "weight": 0.5,
        "id": "67"
    }]
}
```

The old index is the same but it doesn't have the "weight" parameter.

Edit: I created the index using the portal, so I don't have the exact JSON to create the index, but the fields are roughly like this:

```
   Field                     Type                            Attributes        Analyzer
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      id               Edm.String                      Key, Retrievable   
    name               Edm.String   Searchable, Filterable, Retrievable   Eng-Microsoft
keywords   Collection(Edm.String)   Searchable, Filterable, Retrievable   Eng-Microsoft
  weight               Edm.Double                  Filterable, Sortable
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of the `newindexname` index? Specifically the fields and their data types.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. I created an identical index and sent the same indexing request using PowerShell, and it works fine. Can you double-check that the JSON you posted here is exactly what you sent in the request?

Comment: @BruceJohnston Turns out I made a mistake while creating the index from the portal, and chose `Edm.String` for a field when I meant to choose `Collection(Edm.String)`. I've recreated the index and everything looks fine. Sorry for taking your time with a trivial mistake.

Answer (score 5):

The reason I got the error was because I made a mistake and was trying to send a `Collection(Edm.String)` when the actual type on the index was `Edm.String`.

Comment: Hi, How did you found and debug the issue?. I am having same sort of issue. ```azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: () The request is invalid. Details: A null value was found with the expected type 'search.documentFields[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'search.documentFields[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.
Code: 
Message: The request is invalid. Details: A null value was found with the expected type 'search.documentFields[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'search.documentFields[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.```